# C printf puts a tab in the middle of the output

Tags: c, printf, whitespace

Code in question is:

```
frac = i & 0x007FFFFF;
nanBit = (frac & 0x00400000)>>22;
exp = (i & 0x7F800000)>>23;
sign = (i & 0x80000000)>>31;
printf("SignBit %d, expBits %d, fractBits 0x%08X\n", sign, exp, frac);
```

Is outputting a tab after expBits, before the exp %d.  Even when I copy and pasted the code for some reason there was a tab like so:

```
printf("SignBit %d, expBits %d, fractBits 0x%08X\n", sign, exp, frac);
```

While the actual code looks like:

```
printf("SignBit %d, expBits %d, fractBits 0x%08X\n", sign, exp, frac);
```

Edit:  I am noticing that the tab is not actually even being shown in the post, only in the editor.

Comment: Why does it output a tab

Comment: what are the types of all there variables ?

Comment: More generically a section of whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an actual tab in your source code. It just happens to line up with a tabstop so that it's only one space wide in your editor. Ask your editor to search for a tab.